# Rails render partial Ajax Error BUT correct response shown in Debugger

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to trigger an additionnal ajax query on an existing link using unobstrusive Javascript.

The Query is going to the server and processed, returning for the test the string "javascript template ok".

But, the ajax "success" function is never called. In place, it is the "error" function that is triggered...

I looked in the Chrome Debugger and I can see the response text coming back from the server, but never is the "success" method called... :-(

My call is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(response) {   
        $("#details").html(response);
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(){ 
        alert("Error\nData could not be retrieve from the server");
    },
    url: '/treeview/show/1538.js',
    cache: false,
});
```

(url is harcoded in this example). The same Url in the browser gets the correct data with no layout :-)

Removing the ".js" in the url returns the html template with layout and the update of the "details" div is achieved correctly...

The controller is

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.js   { render :inline => "JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE !" }
    end
```

Thank you

EDIT :

Here is the object returned from the ajax query (first argument of error: function(jqXHR) ):

```
Object
    abort: function ( statusText ) {
    always: function () {
    complete: function () {
    done: function () {
    error: function () {
    fail: function () {
    getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
    getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
    overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
    pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    progress: function () {
    promise: function ( obj ) {
    readyState: 4
    responseText: "JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE !"
    setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
    state: function () {
    status: 200
    statusCode: function ( map ) {
    statusText: "OK"
    success: function () {
    then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    __proto__: Object
```

So I get the correct response text ??!! Where can be the error then ? :-s

Comment: have you tried passing `dataType: 'script'` and create a `js.erb` template instead of rendering inline?

Comment: @Stephane: there are already a lot of answers which seem to be pointing in the right direction afaik. Yet you do not react to any of them? How can we help you then? Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not explicitly specify the `dataType` option for `jQuery.ajax` so jQuery infers it to be `script` (relying on MIME type served by Rails). Since `JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE !` is not a valid Javascript statement, parser error is thrown. There are two options to get `success` callback called instead of `error`:

Explicitly specify `dataType` as `text`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    // ...
});
```

Or return valid Javascript from controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js { render :inline => "{}" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that the response might get evaluated as javascript code and therefore throwing an error which gets caught?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not sure about this one, but maybe one of this helps:

Use [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and [`fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) instead of error/success. Like this:

```
$.ajax({ ...}).done(...).fail(...);
```

**or**

Try using the correct function arguments in the success/error callbacks. Maybe jQuery doesn't like the signature and thus does not call the function?

Comment: "success" is correct.  "error" is the pre-1.8 way which is replaced by "fail".  "done" is the new way of doing what was "complete".  "done" is not the same as "success" as it will fire no matter want the result of the call was.

Answer (score 0):

to your ajax call, add

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and, controller

```
format.js   render :text => { :some_data => "JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE !" }.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your error call to pass the error data to the DOM:

```
error: function(data){ console.log(data); }
```

Then you will see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
$.post('/treeview/show/1538.js', function(response, data){
  $("#details").html(data.responseText);
}).error(function(){
  alert("Error\nData could not be retrieve from the server");
})
```

Optional in your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js   { render text: "JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE !" }
end
```

Try it.